# jQuery ajax not downloading scripts in response, not working only in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a 2 sites hosted env with CORS enabled with the following:

a jQuery script on **SITE1** that's basically

```
$.ajax({
    url: "SITE2/source.html",
    type: 'GET',
    success: data => {
      $(this.el).html(data);
    },
  });
```

data is a whole page (it is what it is) with its scripts and its html, like for example

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="SITE2/magic_library.js"></script>
...some html...
<script>
    window.magicLibrary.doSomething()
</script>
...
```

- in FFox/safari everything works fine
- in the network tab of **chrome** there is no call to fetch SITE2/magic_library.js
- `window.magicLibrary.doSomething()` is run, but fails because magicLibrary does not exists since the script hasn't been downloaded

any hint on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who could have the same issue:

the issue was due too restrictive permission-policy headers, a working draft that is honored only by chrome at the day I'm writing.

https://caniuse.com/permissions-policy